# Async Validators Angular 2 Service undefined? Bug?

Tags: validation, asynchronous, angular

I have a problem with calling the backend from my Angular2 async validator. I'm using the "final" version of Angular2.

```
constructor(private formBuilder: FormBuilder,
          private profileService: ProfileService,
          private authService: AuthService,
          private router: Router) {
```

}

```
ngOnInit() {
this.registerForm = this.formBuilder.group({
username:  ['', [Validators.required, Validators.pattern('^[a-zA-Z0-9_]*$'), Validators.minLength(6),
  Validators.maxLength(20)], this.validateUsername],
email: ['', [Validators.required, this.validateEmail, Validators.maxLength(30)]],
password: ['', [Validators.required, Validators.pattern('^.*(?=.{8,})(?=.*[a-zA-Z])(?=.*)(?=.*[!#$%&? "]).*$')]],
confirmPassword: ['', [Validators.required]]},
    {
      validator: this.matchingPasswords('password', 'confirmPassword')
    });
```

}

```
  validateUsername(control: FormControl): {[key: string]: any} {
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
      this.profileService.isUsernameAvailable(control.value).subscribe(res => {
        if (res) {
          resolve(null);
        } else {
          resolve({ validateUsername: {valid: false} });
        }
      });
    });
  }
```

The service gets initialized and even if I call it inside the validateUsername Function it works for console.log().

Error is:
Can't read property "profileService" from undefined.

Is this a bug? Or did i mess something up? Looking into this for hours already.

Service Code:

```
   isUsernameAvailable(username: string): Observable<string> {
   return this.http.get('user?name=').map(res => res.json()).catch(this.handleError);;
  }
```

Edit:

```
@Component({
  selector: 'app-register',
  templateUrl: './register.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./register.component.css']
})
export class RegisterComponent implements OnInit {
```

Full Error Msg:

```
main.bundle.js:44225 EXCEPTION: Cannot read property 'profileService' of undefinedErrorHandler.handleError @ main.bundle.js:44225next @ main.bundle.js:29109schedulerFn @ main.bundle.js:30625SafeSubscriber.__tryOrUnsub @ main.bundle.js:574SafeSubscriber.next @ main.bundle.js:523Subscriber._next @ main.bundle.js:476Subscriber.next @ main.bundle.js:440Subject.next @ main.bundle.js:2027EventEmitter.emit @ main.bundle.js:30617onError @ main.bundle.js:31257onHandleError @ main.bundle.js:64707ZoneDelegate.handleError @ main.bundle.js:89163Zone.runTask @ main.bundle.js:89095ZoneTask.invoke @ main.bundle.js:89260
main.bundle.js:44230 ORIGINAL STACKTRACE:ErrorHandler.handleError @ main.bundle.js:44230next @ main.bundle.js:29109schedulerFn @ main.bundle.js:30625SafeSubscriber.__tryOrUnsub @ main.bundle.js:574SafeSubscriber.next @ main.bundle.js:523Subscriber._next @ main.bundle.js:476Subscriber.next @ main.bundle.js:440Subject.next @ main.bundle.js:2027EventEmitter.emit @ main.bundle.js:30617onError @ main.bundle.js:31257onHandleError @ main.bundle.js:64707ZoneDelegate.handleError @ main.bundle.js:89163Zone.runTask @ main.bundle.js:89095ZoneTask.invoke @ main.bundle.js:89260
main.bundle.js:44231 TypeError: Cannot read property 'profileService' of undefined
    at http://localhost:4200/main.bundle.js:50624:18
    at new ZoneAwarePromise (http://localhost:4200/main.bundle.js:89434:29)
    at RegisterComponent.validateUsername (http://localhost:4200/main.bundle.js:50623:16)
    at http://localhost:4200/main.bundle.js:7776:49
    at Array.map (native)
    at _executeAsyncValidators (http://localhost:4200/main.bundle.js:7776:23)
    at FormControl.asyncValidator (http://localhost:4200/main.bundle.js:7763:28)
    at FormControl.AbstractControl._runAsyncValidator (http://localhost:4200/main.bundle.js:21641:41)
    at FormControl.AbstractControl.updateValueAndValidity (http://localhost:4200/main.bundle.js:21615:22)
    at FormControl.setValue (http://localhost:4200/main.bundle.js:21878:14)ErrorHandler.handleError @ main.bundle.js:44231next @ main.bundle.js:29109schedulerFn @ main.bundle.js:30625SafeSubscriber.__tryOrUnsub @ main.bundle.js:574SafeSubscriber.next @ main.bundle.js:523Subscriber._next @ main.bundle.js:476Subscriber.next @ main.bundle.js:440Subject.next @ main.bundle.js:2027EventEmitter.emit @ main.bundle.js:30617onError @ main.bundle.js:31257onHandleError @ main.bundle.js:64707ZoneDelegate.handleError @ main.bundle.js:89163Zone.runTask @ main.bundle.js:89095ZoneTask.invoke @ main.bundle.js:89260
main.bundle.js:50624 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'profileService' of undefined
```

Comment: Your error is not clear enough. Can you please post your @component declaration and error that you are getting in your console?

Comment: edited it, thanks for the help!

Comment: btw. my component is empty because i load everything at the appmodule